# Database scheme in dao depending on controller endpoint

Tags: java, spring

I have just started with Java Spring and am getting familiar with the framework.

Let's say I have a controller with two endpoints

`"/remove_old"`

`"/remove_new"`

They do the same job: `controller layer` -> `service layer` -> `DAO` except for databases which should be used in dao methods - those are different. As I understand, this can be nicely handled by Spring with no change in the service layer. How should I organize my beans to make it the most appropriate way? The only solution I can think of so far is to autowire everything and then expose `Dao::setDatabase` method which would be called at the controller layer.

Comment: Hi&Welcome! Sounds like a job for (good ole) [AbstractRoutingDataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html)! Where (controller) facades would set some (thread/(better?) "request" bound) "context" invoking the same services/daos... (Concrete data source will be derived from "context".)

Comment: In such cases, there should two services, each talking to different DAO: one for remove_old and another for remove_new. Invoke these sevices accordingly in controller methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a spring-boot3, ARD-solution:

([starter-used](https://start.spring.io/#!&language=java&platformVersion=3.0.0&packaging=jar&artifactId=routing-ds-demo&packageName=com.example.routingds.demo&dependencies=devtools,lombok,web,data-jpa,h2))

Simple entity:

```java
package com.example.routingds.demo;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
class SomeEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  Long id;
}
```

Plus repo:

```java
package com.example.routingds.demo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface SomeRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Long> {}
```

An enum (for all our data sources/tenants):

```java
package com.example.routingds.demo;

public enum MyTenant {
  OLD, NEW;
}
```

A thingy like ([ref1](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source), [ref2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/spring-abstractroutingdatasource/), [ref3](https://attyuttam.medium.com/dynamic-data-source-routing-using-abstractroutingdatasource-in-spring-boot-d6dbdd644072)...):

```java
package com.example.routingds.demo;

public class MyTenantThreadLocalContextHolder {

  private static ThreadLocal<MyTenant> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();

  public static void set(MyTenant tenant) {
    threadLocal.set(tenant);
  }

  public static MyTenant get() {
    return threadLocal.get();
  }
}
```

...(we have plenty options here, but this is thread safe & easy to test/static!)

Then a (very) simple controller like:

```java
package com.example.routingds.demo;

import static com.example.routingds.demo.MyTenant.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

@Controller
public class DemoController {

  @Autowired
  private SomeRepository someRepository;

  @DeleteMapping("/remove_new/{id}")
  public void removeNew(@PathVariable Long id) {
    removeInternal(NEW, id);
  }

  @DeleteMapping("/remove_old/{id}")
  public void removeOld(@PathVariable Long id) {
    removeInternal(OLD, id);
  }

  private void removeInternal(MyTenant current, Long id) {
    // set context ...
    MyTenantThreadLocalContextHolder.set(current);
    // and "just delete" (ard+context will choose correct DS):
    someRepository.deleteById(id);
  }
}
```

Lets go wire it:

`application.properties`:

```properties
fallback.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./data/fallback
fallback.datasource.username=sa
fallback.datasource.password=
#fallback.datasource. ... more if you like/need
old.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./data/old
old.datasource.username=sa
old.datasource.password=
# ...
new.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./data/new
new.datasource.username=sa
new.datasource.password=
# ...
# assuming all dbs initialized , otherwise set these (+ un-comment main class):
#spring.sql.init.mode=always
#spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=false

# debug:
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

# https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2717:
spring.jpa.properties.jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode=UNSPECIFIED
```

App/Main/Config:

```java
package com.example.routingds.demo;

import static com.example.routingds.demo.MyTenant.*;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
//import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer;
//import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
//import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RoutingDsDemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(RoutingDsDemoApplication.class, args);
  }
  // load the props:
  @Bean
  @Primary // one should be primary ...
  @ConfigurationProperties("fallback.datasource")
  public DataSourceProperties fallbackDSProps() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("old.datasource")
  public DataSourceProperties oldDSProps() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("new.datasource")
  public DataSourceProperties newDSProps() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
  }

  // the main (abstract routing) data source:
  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DataSource dataSource(
      @Qualifier("masterDS") DataSource masterDS,
      @Qualifier("newDS") DataSource newDS,
      @Qualifier("oldDS") DataSource oldDS) {
    return new AbstractRoutingDataSource() {
      { // inline instance:
        setTargetDataSources( // ! we operationally use only OLD, NEW:
            Map.of(
                // lookup key, data source:
                OLD, oldDS,
                NEW, newDS
            )
        );
        //... but as a default/fallback/no-context:
        setDefaultTargetDataSource(masterDS);
        afterPropertiesSet();
      }
      // inline override:
      @Override
      protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return MyTenantThreadLocalContextHolder.get();
      }
    };
  }

  // the "slaves" / underlying / your DS's:
  @Bean // default/master/backup/unused:
  DataSource masterDS(DataSourceProperties props) {
    return props.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build(); 
  }

  @Bean
  DataSource oldDS(@Qualifier("oldDSProps") DataSourceProperties props) {
    return props.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
  }

  @Bean
  DataSource newDS(@Qualifier("newDSProps") DataSourceProperties props) {
    return props.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
  }

// for (script) db initialization, we might need this (+'sql.init.mode=always'):
//  @Bean
//  DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer initOld(@Qualifier("oldDS") DataSource oldDS, SqlInitializationProperties settings) {
//    return new SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer(oldDS, settings);
//  }
//
//  @Bean
//  DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer initNew(@Qualifier("newDS") DataSource newDS, SqlInitializationProperties settings) {
//    return new SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer(newDS, settings);
//  }
}
```

Init schema (`src/main/resources/schema.sql`):

```sql
create table some_entity (id bigint not null, primary key (id));
create sequence some_entity_seq start with 1 increment by 50;
```

#### TESTING TIME!! :))

```java
package com.example.routingds.demo;

import static com.example.routingds.demo.MyTenant.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc // we will test the controller!
class RoutingDsDemoApplicationTests {

  // tenant/DS dependent test IDs:
  static final EnumMap<MyTenant, Set<Long>> TEST_IDS = new EnumMap<>(
      Map.of(
          OLD, new HashSet<>(),
          NEW, new HashSet<>()
      )
  );

  @TestConfiguration // some "test setup":
  static class TestDataConfig {

    @Bean
    InitializingBean testData(SomeRepository repo) { // <- normal/autowired repo
      return () -> {
        // for OLD and NEW (tenant):
        Arrays.stream(MyTenant.values())
          .forEach((t) -> { 
            // set context/db:
            MyTenantThreadLocalContextHolder.set(t);
            // clean up (we shouldn't need this/DANGER):
            // repo.deleteAll();
            // save 100 SomeEntity's, and store ids to TEST_IDS:
            IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach((i) -> {
              TEST_IDS.get(t).add(
                repo.save(new SomeEntity()).getId()
              );
            });
        });
      };
    }
  }

  @Autowired
  MockMvc mockMvc;
  @Autowired
  SomeRepository helper;

  @Test
  void testRemoveOld() {
    // for each (known) OLD id:
    TEST_IDS.get(OLD).stream().forEach((id) -> {
      try {
        mockMvc
            .perform(delete("/remove_old/" + id))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        fail(ex);
      }
    });
    // verify deleted:
    MyTenantThreadLocalContextHolder.set(OLD);
    TEST_IDS.get(OLD).stream().forEach((id) -> {
      assertFalse(helper.existsById(id));
    });
  }

  @Test
  void testRemoveNew() {
    // for each (known) NEW id:
    TEST_IDS.get(NEW).stream().forEach((id) -> {
      try {
        mockMvc
            .perform(delete("/remove_new/" + id))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        fail(ex);
      }
    });
    // verify deleted:
    MyTenantThreadLocalContextHolder.set(NEW);
    TEST_IDS.get(NEW).stream().forEach((id) -> {
      assertFalse(helper.existsById(id));
    });
  }
}
```

passes:

```bash
Results:

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

See also:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-access.configure-two-datasources
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization

Comment: That's just awesome! First of all, thank you for pointing out to AbstractRoutingDataSource in your comment - that was very helpful. And then thanks again for the answer! I ended up doing a similar thing, yet it was really helpful to see your example